# vue cli how to create a custom chunk and hook in index.html?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I want to create a custom chunk and attach in generated index.html. I created a custom project using `vue create .` and added a `vue.config.js` file.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          utiltest: {
            name: 'utiltest',
            test: /utils[\\/]test/,
            priority: -30,
            chunks: 'initial',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I have some util functions in `src/utils/test` for which I want to create a separate bundle and attach in index.html. Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-utiltest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

But in generated index.html file its not creating the chunk for utiltest, it has just these 2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Note: I am importing functions from utils/test in my main.js like

```
import testHook from '@/utils/test';
...
testHook();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to create a new chunk, you add another entry point. Now two files are available in the output directory. `public/index.js` and `public/untiltest.js`.

```js
module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  entry: {
    index: './src/index',
    utiltest: './src/utiltest',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  },
  ....
```

You can also [name the chunks](https://vuedose.tips/naming-webpack-chunks-on-lazy-loaded-routes-in-vuejs/) you want to import in vue

```js
const routeOptions = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/about', name: 'About' },
  { path: '/login', name: 'Login' }
]

const routes = routeOptions.map(route => {
  return {
    ...route,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `../views/${route.name}.vue`)
  }
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

In a normal html file, you could also combine this with the [html webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)

```js
  ...
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Vue App',
    template: './src/template.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    chunks: ['index', 'utiltest'],
  }),
```